# Deleting TCHAR pointer

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am trying to do make a C++ hello world that supports Unicode, but I am a little stuck.

I made a pointer to a TCHAR [I think its a char array], and after using it, I attempt to delete it. It crashes saying `Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`.

Checking the interwebs, someone said it was because the wrong delete was used. I tried both deletes, but it still gives the same message.

Did I miss something obvious?

Code I tried:

```
TCHAR *str=TEXT("おはよう, World!");
delete[] str;
```

Also tried:

```
TCHAR *str=TEXT("おはよう, World!");
delete str;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TCHAR *str=TEXT("おはよう, World!");
```

You're not allocating anything, so there's no need to delete the memory. Simply don't call `delete[]`. `TEXT` is a macro, not a function returning some memory you're supposed to manage yourself.

It's like calling delete after

```
char* x = "bla";
delete[] x;
```

Just illegal, since you don't own the memory.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to call `delete` if you called `new`, Since you didn't. You don't need to call `delete` here.
Your string here is created on a implementation defined memory area and not dynamic memory(aka heap)

Comment: Good to know. I thought I had to delete before a pointer to some data goes out of scope.